# Wordpress returning 301 to itself

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, self-hosting

I have setup a Wodpress site using Sophos UTM Webserver Protection as reverse proxy. After changing the sites URL from the servers IP to the correct URL following [this guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/) and using the [Better Search Replace](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin Wordpress returns a 301 redirect to itself, leading to an infinite loop. How can this be resolved?

From request header:

```
{"name":"Host","value":"www.myurl.com"}
```

From response header:

```
{"name":"Location","value":"https://www.myurl.com/"}
```

Also:

`https://www.myurl.com/wp-admin`is changed to `https://server-ip/wp-admin/`

Comment: Is it trying to bounce between HTTPS and HTTP? Look in your network tab in your dev console to see what's happening.

Comment: Done that. The request header is https, the response header is also https.

Comment: Updated detials from request and response headers.

Comment: Open your database and look in the `wp_options` table to make sure the `siteurl` and `home` are set correctly.

Comment: Both `siteurl` and `home`are set to `https://www.myurl.com`

Comment: Please see update above regarding access to wp-admin